Passing in custom command invocations to custom function in bash
I have a few custom bash functions.
function hello() {
   echo hello 
}

function goodbye() {
    echo goodbye
}

function wrapper() {
    $1  
}

From the terminal, if I call hello && goodbye, I get
hello
goodbye

as expected.
But when I call wrapper "hello && goodbye", I only get
hello

I've been scratching my head over this for too long. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Use eval "$1" to execute a shell command.

The shell doesn't parse syntax like && after expanding variables. The only processing it does is word-splitting and wildcard expansion. So && is treated as a literal.

You can reproduce this without a function: command="hello && goodbye"; $command → hello

Does this answer your question? How can I execute a command stored in a variable?

There are other existing questions too that you can find by googling something like how do i run a shell command stored in a string site:stackoverflow.com. E.g. Run a string as a command within a Bash script

Using the same text for the function names as for the text printed by the functions is just making it harder for you to see what's happening. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Thanks for the link! I didn't have a deep enough understanding of what was happening to come up with a succinct enough google search; I was trying searches like "How to pass a command into a function". But it definitely makes sense that the issue was with how the variable is being expanded, to be run. Thanks again!

is this the sort of thing you are after ?
function Hello(){ 
    echo "hello it's $(date)" 
}
function ByeBye(){ 
    echo "goodbye it's $(date)" 
}

function wrapper(){
    IFS=' && ' read -ra CMDS <<< "$*"
    for cmd in "${CMDS[@]}"; do
        $cmd
    done
}

wrapper "Hello && ByeBye"
hello it's Sun 11 Aug 2024 22:25:41 BST
goodbye it's Sun 11 Aug 2024 22:25:41 BST


Thanks! That looks more complicated than what I was looking for. I think I was just looking for eval $1.

This probably doesn't meet the intention in cases where Hello fails, and doesn't generalize well if other types of syntax like Hello || ByeBye starts to get mixed in.
